# Regex to match 10 or 12 digits only

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I tried to write a regex to match a 10 or 12 digits number combination. like:

1234567890   - True
 123456789012 - True
 12345678901  - False
 123456- False

1234567890123- False

Only match either 10 or 12 digits.
I tried this:

```
"^[0-9]{10}|[0-9]{12}$"
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You're close!

This is the regex you're looking for: `^(\d{10}|\d{12})$`. It checks for digits (with `\d`). The rest is more or less your code, with the exception of the parenthesis. It captures each group. You could loose those, if you want to work without it!

[See it in action here](https://regex101.com/r/SeItrZ/1)

Comment: Just to add to my answer: [regex101.com](http://regex101.com) is a great way to learn regex. Each time you need it, just fiddle around and keep an eye at the legend at the bottom right. I used to suck at regex, but that site taught me a lot just by trial and error!

Answer (score 4):

there is another approach, you can do it like this way.

```
^\d{10}(\d{2})?$
```

Comment: Clever, but why? I feel like `\d{10}|\d{12}` is much clearer

Comment: can't deny. undoubtedly \d{10}|\d{12} this one is cleaner and more understandable also. but as I know another approach thought of sharing it.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex either matches 10 digits at the beginning of a string (with any characters more allowed after that), or 12 digits at the end of the string. One option to make your regex work is:

```
"^[0-9]{10}$|^[0-9]{12}$"
```

although it's better to use raw strings for the pattern:

```
r'^[0-9]{10}$|^[0-9]{12}$'
```